# Javascript, My Function is miscalculating the change due to a customer in dollar bills

Tags: javascript, function

```
const cash = document.getElementById("cash");
const changeDue = document.getElementById("change-due");
const purchaseBtn = document.getElementById("purchase-btn");
const cashInDrawer = document.getElementById("cash-in-drawer");
const totalSpan = document.getElementById("total")

let price = 1.87;

let cid = [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
];

const billValues = {
  "PENNY": 0.01,
  "NICKLE": 0.05,
  "DIME": 0.1,
  "QUARTER": 0.25,
  "ONE": 1,
  "FIVE": 5,
  "TEN": 10,
  "TWENTY": 20,
  "ONE HUNDRED": 100
}

const totalCash = cid.reduce((acc, arr) => 
acc + arr[1], 0
) 

const totalCashRoundedUp = (Math.round(totalCash * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);

cid.forEach((arr) => {
 cashInDrawer.innerHTML += `
 <li>${arr[0]}: $${arr[1]}</li>`
})

totalSpan.textContent = `$${price}`;

const convertArray = (arr) => {
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let current = arr[i];
    let existingIndex = result.findIndex(subArr => subArr[0] === current[0]);
    if (existingIndex === -1) {
      result.push([current[0], current[1]]);
    } else {
      result[existingIndex][1] += current[1];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

const calculateChange = (amountTendered, price) => {
  let change = amountTendered - price;
  let totalChange = [];
  const cidR = cid.reverse();
  for (let i = 0; i < cidR.length; i++) {
    let cash = cidR[i];
    let billValue = billValues[cash[0]];

    while (change >= billValue) {
      change -= billValue
      totalChange.push([cash[0], billValue])
      
    }
    if (change === billValue) {
      totalChange.push([cash[0], billValue]);
      change = 0;
    }
  }

  return convertArray(totalChange);
}


const writeChangeDue = (arr) => {
 const writtenChangeDue = arr.forEach((arr) => {
    changeDue.innerHTML += `<p class="change-due">${arr[0]}: ${arr[1]} </p>`
    return writtenChangeDue
  })
}
purchaseBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  changeDue.innerHTML = ``
  if(cash.value < price){
    alert("Customer does not have enough money to purchase the item")
  } else if(cash.value == price){
    changeDue.innerHTML += `<p>No change due - customer paid with exact cash</p>`
  } else if(cash.value > totalCashRoundedUp){
    changeDue.innerHTML += `<p>Status: INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS</p>`
  } else {
    changeDue.innerHTML += `<p class="change-due">Status: OPEN</p>` 
    writeChangeDue(calculateChange(cash.value, price))
  }
})
```

This code is supposed to output the bills that the customer should receive for his change and the amount for each bill. However I've run it to a problem, when the customer is receiving pennies as part of his change it is always one short. For Example when cash.value is = 100, the output for changeDue.innerHTML is TWENTY: 80, TEN: 10, FIVE: 5, ONE: 3, DIME: 0.1, PENNY: 0.02(here it should be 0.03).

I tried to add another if statement for when change is down to the last penny to add another Penny array to Total Change but no luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Something's Wrong With My Code To Calculate Change Money](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37713965/somethings-wrong-with-my-code-to-calculate-change-money)

Comment: The dupe is a different programming language, but the same problem with the same solutions. One solution, use integers instead of floats.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)